# Giving error 'Error Bad file descriptor' during execution of Perl

Tags: java, perl

**[*Question Updated by following the commentator's comments*]** When I am using the following command for executing prop.obj
**"perl sendXssl.pl *hostname* *port* prop.obj"**, It is giving error as "Error Bad file descriptor, ssl_error=SSL connect attempt failed at sendXssl.pl line 6".
Please help me to solve this.
My Perl program is given below...

## Perl

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw( SSL_VERIFY_NONE );
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
$|=1;

my $sock = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
 PeerHost => $ARGV[0],
 PeerPort => $ARGV[1],
 SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE)
 or die "error=$!, ssl_error=$IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR";

print $sock "X";
my $data ;
my $file = $ARGV[2];
open(my $fh,'<',$file) or die "Error 2 $!\n";
{
 local $/;
 $data = <$fh>;
}
close($fh);

my $pack = $data;
print $sock $pack;
```

I created **prop.obj** object from the following java file

## Java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    public class PropertiesX {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String[] s = new String[1];
                s[0] = "notepad.exe";
                Properties p = new Properties();
                p.put("commandArgs",s);
                p.setProperty("parent", "c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("prop.obj");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(p);
                oos.close();
                System.out.println(p.toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an explanation of what your program is supposed to do. Then [edit] your Perl program to include `use strict` and `use warnings` and make sure it compiles. Also, please include the **full error message**. Do not cut anything off, like the line number. That's important to see where the error is. In its current form we cannot answer your question, because we have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: 1) You have two `die "Error $!\n"` that could produce the message, but you didn't specify which one is producing the error. 2) `new IO::Socket::SSL->new(...)` should be `IO::Socket::SSL->new(...)` 3) `IO::Socket::SSL->new` sets `$@` on error. 4) ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`

Comment: Why are you using a mode of `"+<"` when opening that file when all you're doing is reading from it? Also, use [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) instead. It's a better way to read a file's contents into a scalar.

Comment: Hi @ikegami 1) This error is coming from the first die. 2) I  updated the same but still, there is the same error from the first die. 4) I used `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` and declared all the variable using `my` keyword. Plz help

Comment: Oops, I was wrong about `$!`/`$@`. I thought you were using IO::Socket::INET. IO::Socket::SSL says to use `or die "error=$!, ssl_error=$IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR";`

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the direct and indirect method syntax together:

```
$sock = new IO::Socket::SSL->new(
#       ~~~                  ~~~
  PeerHost => $ARGV[0],
  PeerPort => $ARGV[1],
  SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE)
```

Remove the first `new` and try again.

Comment: It is giving same error again "Error Bad file descriptor"

Comment: I am new to PERL and I am getting this error when I am executing it from the Command line. The screenshot is attached now to the question.

Comment: You told Perl to throw the error. Use different error messages in the two places where you tell it to `die` and you'll at least know where it happens.

Comment: @PawanDwivedee if you read [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) for `die`, you'll see how to get the file name and line number where that particular `die` was called included in the error message.

Comment: Thanks, @Shawn and choroba, I did the same and got that error is coming from the first die.

Comment: @PawanDwivedee: Can you add $SSL_ERROR to the message, too?

Comment: Error is `error=Bad file descriptor, ssl_error=SSL connect attempt failed at sendXssl.pl line 6.`